# Unsupported "export *" Error with Chakra UI Icons in Next.js Application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, chakra-ui

**Description:**

I am working on a Next.js application and using the Chakra UI library for styling and components. However, I encountered an issue with the Chakra UI icons package during the build process.

**Error Message:**

```
./node_modules/@chakra-ui/icons/dist/index.mjs
Error: It's currently unsupported to use "export *" in a client boundary. Please use named exports instead.
```

**Environment: Node 19**

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.0",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.15",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@types/node": "20.4.4",
    "@types/react": "18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.12",
    "framer-motion": "^10.13.0",
    "next": "13.4.12",
    "postcss": "8.4.27",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}
```

**Steps I've Taken:**

1. I made sure that I am using the latest version of Chakra UI and its dependencies.
2. I have already tried using named imports directly from the package as follows:

```js
import { BellIcon, ChevronDownIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';
```

Despite taking these steps, the issue persists, and I cannot successfully build my application. I suspect there might be something wrong with the Chakra UI icons package or how I am using it in my Next.js project.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue, too. Just figured out that the resolution is to put `"use client"` at the top of the files that are importing Chakra-UI. I've had issues before with Chakra-UI not being compatible with Next.js's app router when in `"use server"` mode before, but I got jammed with the same error as you because I put the `"use client"` in the wrong place. I ended up having to add it to the pages in my use case instead of just the components.

Unfortunately current versions of Chakra-UI, as of this writing, are incompatible with `"use server"` for a lot of use cases. Whenever you get a Chakra-UI error in Next.js app router, I recommend adding `"use client"` until the problem goes away, then reverse-engineering to figure out which file actually needed it.